# capistrano one username for multiple users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have multiple developers working on the same application in rails.  I am trying to get capistrano setup to use one login (preferably with public keys vs. password).  I can't seem to find anything on the net that covers this.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `set :user, "username"` instruction to set a generic username like `deploy`
Then you can add all their public keys to the `/home/deploy/.ssh/authorized_keys` file

Comment: you know whats stupid... I had this webpage open...http://dirk.net/category/capistrano/  I guess I over thought that, I was expecting something much more involved, thank you.

Comment: ok I setup a username (deploy), added my (toby) public key to /home/deploy/.ssh/authorized_keys, and its asking for a password, if I enter the password it works fine, but if not it wont.

Answer (score 0):

I added to config/deploy.rb the following:

```
namespace :deploy do
  [...]
  set :user, "my_username"
  [...]
end
```

and a public key authentication worked.